# how can I start the glassfish on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, glassfish

I am trying to install glassfish on ubuntu 16.04

I used this tutorial successfully

http://idroot.net/linux/install-glassfish-ubuntu-16-04/

but when i do the following it gives me this error

```
 $ glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start 
serverNoStart

Command start-domain failed.
```

Answer (score -1):

Try starting GlassFish by using asadmin in the glassfish4/glassfish/bin folder.

```
$ glassfish4/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

Have you checked the logs for any more helpful errors in `glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log` ?